# If Statement Causing Undefined Local Variable/Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

<strike>Why would adding this HAML if statement return 'ftp' as an undefined local variable/method?
When I remove the if/else statement everything runs as it should.</strike>

```
- if @contest.size > 2
  / Do stuff
- else
  - team.fantasy_team_players.each do |ftp|
    - player = @owned[ftp.id]
    .col-md-6
      = "Words..."
      = ftp.position
```

**Update**

Adding the correct indentation fixed the undefined error. However, .col-md-6 doesn't render when the page is loaded. Any thoughts as to why that's happening?

Comment: i think indentation wrong again, but i not sure, can't test now.

Comment: Would you update your answer please?

Comment: try this http://pastebin.com/NBXSTy0k

Comment: and i not sure is right way assignment in views `- player = @owned[ftp.id]` what you want achive?

Comment: @localhost if you have a new question you should, well, ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: This question is still about indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation on your `haml` views should be:

```
- if @contest.size > 2
  / Do stuff...
- else
  - team.players.each do |ftp|
    .col-md-6
      = ftp.position
```

Comment: That fixed that particular problem. I updated the question. Would you take a look at it?